# How to get rounded edge scroll bar in IE10?

Tags: scrollbar, internet-explorer-10

Am using following css to change the scroll bar color

```
<style>

body
{
  scrollbar-face-color: #EEEEEE;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFFFFF;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: #CCCCCC;
  scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #FFFFFF;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #AAAAAA;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: #000000;
  scrollbar-track-color: #EEEEEE;
}
</style>
```

color changed. But what is the way to get the rounded edge scroll bar in IE10?

Answer (score 3):

There isn’t a way to style scrollbars in IE, except for the colour. You can see the full list of CSS properties for styling scrollbars at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466154.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are ways of styling scrollbars in IE if you are up for using javascript. You can only change colours by using CSS. By using javascript you can create a scrollbar that is styleable with css and replaces the native scrollbar of the browser. There are several examples of this as for instance [this one](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/scrollbar_themes_demo.html) which is using jQuery.